# How do I open URLs in the background of an existing Chrome window with Terminal on MacOS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal, zsh, terminal.app

Currently I am building an iOS shortcut to open multiple links through SSH on my MacBook and I am wondering if it is possible to open URLs in the background of Google Chrome without losing focus of the current tab.

Which command do I need to use?